# Java how to sort from Text File

Tags: java, sorting

```
CH0001 , John
CH0002 , Alex
```

Above is the coach.txt which contains id and name. I'm still new to Java. How do I sort it according to the name.

```
CH0002 , Alex
CH0001 , John
```

My expected output would be like this. Kindly appreciate for you guys help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many alternatives.

The main issue here should be comparing the lines not according to the alphanumeric value of the whole line, but separating the lines into columns, and using the second column's alphanumeric value as the comparator.

Comment: I did the way u mentioned, and managed to do it! Thanks man!